# Unity: Define UI Buttons in Input Manager

Tags: unity-game-engine

Inside a Canvas I have UI Buttons that should be responsible for "left", "right" and "jump". Is it possible to define them as responsible Buttons in the Input Manager instead of Keyboard Buttons?

[image]

If not, how can I simulate the left and right horizontal Input Events in UI Buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get what I needed with CrossPlatformInput from Standard Assets as shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqomLumqwCk

Answer (score 0):

Never heard about simulating key presses in an easy way, often it is accomplished by just replacing `Input.GetKey` with a custom `bool` that you control with your code, but you can make `Input Events` in `Event System`. For example, move to the left.

```
void LeftArrow()
{
    EventSystem eventSystem = EventSystem.Current;
    AxisEventData axisData = new AxisEventData(eventSystem);

    axisData.Reset();
    axisData.moveDir = MoveDirection.Left;
    ExecuteEvents.Execute(eventSystem.currentSelectedGameObject, axisData, ExecuteEvents.moveHandler);
}
```

Or for buttons. Submit Button for example.

```
void SubmitButton()
{
    EventSystem eventSystem = EventSystem.Current;
    BaseEventData baseData = new BaseEventData(eventSystem);

    baseData.Reset();
    ExecuteEvents.Execute(eventSystem.currentSelectedGameObject, baseData, ExecuteEvents.submitHandler);
}
```